# Explicit construction of entity type 'Artist' in query is not allowed

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Compile just fine but execution fail with the error in the title.

ArtistService.cs

```
public class ArtistService : IArtistService
{
    public List<Artist>  ArtistDetail()  
    {
        using (ArtistDataContext db = new ArtistDataContext())
        {
            return (from artist in db.Artists

                select new Artist()
                {
                    Id = artist.Id,
                    Artist_name = Artist.Artist_name
                }).ToList();     <=== error happened here
        }
    }
}
```

code Behind

```
private List<ArtistServiceReference.Artist> ArtistDetail()
{
    ArtistServiceReference.ArtistServiceClient client = new 
    ArtistServiceReference.ArtistServiceClient();

    ArtistServiceReference.Artist[] artists = client.ArtistDetail();

    return artists.ToList();
```

I want to move the Artist List to a DropdownList.

The error is happening in the ArtistService.cs at the end {).ToList();
Any explanation on how to fix this issue?  Thanks

I based my code on this example and this example is working fine.

example code MyService.cs

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public List<Task> GetTasks()
    {
        using (TasksDataContext db = new TasksDataContext())
        {
            return (from task in db.TasksLists
                select new Task()
                {
                    Id = task.taskId,
                    Name = task.taskName,

                }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Example default.aspx.cs

```
private List<TaskService.Task> GetTasks()
{
    TaskService.MyServiceClient client = new TaskService.MyServiceClient();

    TaskService.Task[] tasks = client.GetTasks();

    return tasks.ToList();
}
```

I don't understand why this example will work and not mine.  The only difference was this example is returning to a gridview and I want to return to a dropdownlist.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear. You can't create a new `Artist` as part of a linq query. Can you not just `select artist`?

Comment: Why the other example is working then?

Comment: What is the type of `db.Artists`?

Comment: public System.Data.Linq.Table<Artist> Artists

Comment: If it's already `Artist`s, why are you trying to make new `Artist`s from them? (or are these different classes in different namespaces?)

Comment: Does it means the example I am using is wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Linq to Entities cannot translate the Artist object creation into SQL code (really, what is this supposed to look like?). Linq to Entities can only execute SQL queries and map returned fields to some entity to which it knows how to map (i.e. your DbSet entities). So, you need to execute the query first and then create the Artist entities locally:

```
public class ArtistService : IArtistService
{
    public List<Artist>  ArtistDetail()  
    {
        using (ArtistDataContext db = new ArtistDataContext())
        {
            return (from artist in db.Artists
                    select new { // select only columns you need
                       artist.Id,
                       artist.Artist_name
                    })
                    .AsEnumerable() // execute query
                    .Select(x => new Artist { // create instance of class
                        Id = x.Id,
                        Artist_name = x.Artist_name
                    })
                    .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

BTW it looks like you have `Artist` entities in your `Artists` DbSet. Why not simply return

```
 return db.Artists.ToList();
```

Comment: I am trying your solution with the return db.Artists.ToList().  To populate the dropdownlist on the page_Load I did this.  DropDownList1.DataSource = ArtistDetail();   DropDownList1.DataBind();  It generated an error because I am using in the .aspx page DataTextField="Artist_name" DataSourceID ="Id"

Comment: DropDownList1.DataSource = ArtistDetail();
        DropDownList1.DataBind();  <=== error    Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'DropDownList1'.  Remove one definition. I commented out the first one.  Then I got this error  The DataSourceID of 'DropDownList1' must be the ID of a control of type IDataSource.  A control with ID 'Id' could not be found.

Comment: @user3127986 go to page markup, find this DropDownList control and remove DataSourceID from it

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1"  should I completely remove the ID="DropDownList1"  or I just delete the name ID="" ?  If I remove it I got many errors because I am using the DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

Comment: @user3127986 no, there should be DataSourceID attribute. If its not there, then check code behind - you are assigning it from code

Comment: I got this in the <asp: DropDownList1    DataTextField="Artist_name" DataSourceID ="Id"   I am removing the DataSourceId="id" and......     IT WORKS !!!!!!    Alleluia  !!!    Thanks a lot...  I guess the example I was using is not a good one...   Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3127986 welcome :) Next time read exception message carefully - it often contains all you need to know